# With being ignored by korma (clojure)

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I have the following code:

```
(defentity users
  (database korma-db)
  (has-many tags))

(defentity tags
  (database korma-db)
  (belongs-to users))

(-> (select* users)
    (with tags)
    (fields :address)
    (where {:id 1})
    (as-sql))
```

and it generates the following sql:

```
SELECT "users"."address" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = ?)
```

While I would expect it to include a join to the tags table, by merit of having the `with` macro applied. Clearly this isn't the case, but executing it will produce an empty :tags key in the single returned record.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you try without `fields`?

Comment: Just did, and that fixed it. I didn't expect korma to remove the join if I wasn't selecting any of the tag fields, which is good I suppose, just caught me by surprise. Also odd that it still adds the :tags key but leaves its value empty. But in any case, that did it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, Korma's `with` joins will fail if you don't select the key columns in your `fields`.  I haven't found a way of excluding them and using `with`, but there's another way in a similar question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242097/select-no-fields-from-table-in-korma

Answer (score 0):

did you create the actual referential constraint on the database?
I think I had the same issue once and I fixed it by creating a foreign key when defining the field.
i.e. in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
...
 users_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
)
```